# Hibernate table design for servicecenter

Tags: hibernate

I have below problem for which i have design table. Can someone please help?

1. I have multiple servicecenters in city
2. Each service center can offer multiple services (they are completely different in nature like carwash and plumbing)
3. Each service has price chart for service units
4. Units are also completely different for different services.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds to me as though it's really a SQL database design question in disguise.  Am I right in assuming this?  If so, update your tags.

Comment: No its not.  My question is specific to Hibernate. I want to know how to i map relations between objects to get the desired tables.